# What is this Mandarin(?) joke(?) in Armour of God 2: Operation Condor?

Tags: plot-explanation, armour-of-god-2-operation-condor

In the 1991 Jackie Chan movie *Armour of God 2: Operation Condor*, our heroes are crossing the desert, and take a small break to pee. The following image appears on the screen:

[image]

Given the tone of the movie, this is probably a joke. For those of us who don’t speak Mandarin(?), what does this say?

Comment: Damn China and their... their... *\*shuffles deck, picks card\**... Non-English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it's Cantonese, even though the left text characters are also used in Mandarin, and it says something like the following:

> RIGHT: What's wrong?!
>
> LEFT: The water (urine) is boiling!

.

> RIGHT: **事*!*!
>
> LEFT: 水滚*!

(I'm positive about the left text and fairly certain about the right)

So yeah, it's a joke about how hot it is in the desert, lol. I'll see if I can finish translating the text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the translation above is pretty accurate. I just added the original text used in picture.

> RIGHT: What's wrong?! (喂! 乜野事呀!  )
>
> LEFT:  The water is boiling (水滾啦)

Just one more things, the text is primary used in Cantonese instead of Mandarin